# Neo4J database design: is it OK to have hubs or is it better to split them?

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I'm thinking about the graph database design for my Neo4J (2.0) database and I have a question about its productivity.

Basically, when users add information, they will be able to select various contexts, which will be marked with a @mention sign. By default, they're adding information into the @private context. These contexts will later be used to find relevant nodes (connected to @private context, for example).

The question: is it better for database productivity to have different @private contexts – one for every user. Or is it better to just make one @private context (which will eventually have thousands of connections and become a very central hub), and then use properties of relationships during search.

Simply: As far as traversals are concerned, is it better to have a graph with only a few super-connected nodes, or is it better to split those nodes into as many parts as possible?

Answer (score 2):

Hubs can become a problem when they get real big. Generally Neo4j is said to perform well with moderately connected nodes. Neither densely nor sparsely. Which is a vague thing to say, but hard numbers depend on the specifics of the domain you're modelling. It's generally a good thing to ask yourself how you're going to query the data. Will you almost always fetch contexts for one user, or will you also have queries across users? Writing a test that creates and fills a graph with sample data and then runs queries against it is also a good idea. You can see how changes in the query affect performance. And you can test how the performance will change if your hubs go up to, say 100k relationships.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think that hubs can clog traversals, like if I query a specific type of relationship that happen to also occur between the superconnected hubs and other nodes, will it be an obstacle that those hubs would be included in graph traversals?

Answer (score 1):

Hub nodes will be addressed in the 2.1 release so it will be cheap to check against them.

If you default to private you probably rather want to mark the exception to that? I.e. assume private and only mark @public contexts.

Otherwise I'd probably go with per-user contexts that might be tagged with a label.

Comment: Thanks! So starting from 2.1 it will be OK to have those kind of superconnected nodes without risking them always getting in the way of traversals, right? And yes, @private is assumed by default, if a user wants to make anything public, they mark it with another context, e.g. public or neo4j or anything else. So you think I better make per-user contexts for now, correct? And then maybe when the 2.1 comes out I can merge them.